# OpenCV method unrecognized in QT project using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt, opencv

I coded a little OpenGL Qt project which is able to display textured models. To load BMP files I use OpenCV 'cvLoadImage' method to do the job done. The problem is at the end of the compilation execution. The following error message appears :

```
lnk2019 unresolved external symbol cvLoadImage referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CoreSystem::loadBMPTexture(char const *,enum E_TextureType)" (?loadBMPTexture@CoreSystem@@QEAAXPEBDW4E_TextureType@@@Z)
```

Here's the content of my method :

```
void                    CoreSystem::loadBMPTexture(char const *filename, E_TextureType texType)
{
    IplImage            *image = NULL;

    if ((image = cvLoadImage(filename)) != NULL)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &this->textureID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureID);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        if (texType == MIPMAP)
            gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, image->width,
            image->height,GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
        else
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->width,
            image->height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
}
```

However, my OpenCV library linkage is correct in the linker (I added opencv_highgui245d.lib) and my VC++ directories linkages are correct too (if I comment the code in my function 'loadBMPTexture' the compilation is correct, so my libraries are recognized and so my linkages are corrects). I want to precise that before create a QT project I made the same project but without QT context (just a simple console application) and the program worked perfectly (with the same linkages). But with QT it seems not working. Does QT does not link external OpenCV dependencies ? I'm really lost in front of this situation. Does anyone can help me, please ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.